# Start app when screen off

Tags: android, screen

I want to open my MainActivity class when screen is off. In order to do that i make two class 
ScreenReceiver.java to handle Screen OFF & Screen ON Intents:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }

}
```

And UpdateService for implementing ScreenReceiver:

```
public  class UpdateService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

public void onStart(Context context, Intent intent, int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {
        // your code
         Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
         intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(intent11);
    } else {
        // your code
        Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

So, when i install my app, there are no event when screen is off. please show me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the UpdateService in foreground somewhere in your application??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, intents `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` can only be handled by a receiver registered via function `registerReceiver()`. Defining an `IntentFilter` in manifest.xml does not work for these intents.

Then, you need to make sure `UpdateService:onCreate()` be called in your application, otherwise `ScreenReceiver:onReceiver()` will never be called. You may want to do this when get intent `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

You may change the code to this, and do not forget define the service in manifest:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver {
    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        handleScreenAction(screenOff);
    }

    private void handleScreenAction(boolean screenOff) {
        if (screenOff) {
            // your code
            Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent11);
        } else {
            // your code
            Intent intent11 = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            intent11.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestory() {
        super.onDestory();
        unRegisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    public void onStart(Context context, Intent intent, int startId) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```